# Помогите, пожалуйста, составить SQL запрос по условиям

Tags: mysql, sql

Есть таблица

| id позиции | package_id компл. | status статус | flag флаг |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 55 | 0 | 1 |
| 2 | 66 | 0 | 0 |
| 3 | 55 | 1 | 0 |
| 4 | 77 | 0 | 0 |
| 5 | 66 | 1 | 0 |

Нужно составить SQL запрос, чтобы получить все позиции одного комплекта в соответствии с условиями:

1. искать среди комплектов, у которых есть хоть одна позиция со
   status=0, остальные комплекты не нужны
2. сортировка по id позиции (order by id), чтобы выбрать нужный комплект (ищем комплект с самой старой позицией)
3. в комплекте у всех позиций должен быть flag=0

То есть в этом примере мне надо получить две строки:

| id позиции | package_id комплекта | status статус | flag флаг |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 66 | 0 | 0 |
| 5 | 66 | 1 | 0 |

И что-то в один запрос сделать не получается. Очень прошу помощи или подсказки, куда лучше копать.

Comment: Точная версия MySQL?

Comment: *куда лучше копать* Условие 3 - это SUM(flag <> 0) = 0. Условие 1 - соответственно SUM(status = 0) > 0. Ну а сортировкой и лимитом сами разберётесь. Всё это - в подзапрос, и по его результату выбор отдельных строк,

Comment: mysql версия 5.6

Comment: Значит, оконные функции недоступны - делайте по описанному пути.

Comment: Ну limit тут мне никак не поможет, я же не знаю изначально, сколько позиций будет в комплекте.

Comment: LIMIT нужен не для получения записей из комплекта, а для получения номера этого комплекта, который по условиям должен быть один-единственный.

Comment: Спасибо. А подскажите, пожалуйста, а если мне вот это условие SUM(flag <> 0) = 0 нужно только для тех, у которых статус = 0, а если у позиции статус 1, то флаг может также быть 1, я могу как-то это сюда же добавить?

Comment: Не понял вопроса. Условия-то независимы - зачем их связывать?